# how to show my data in my listview?

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a listview.
and listview is included a share Imagebutton.
when I click on the ImageButton I want to share my text of each item in textview.
The problem is how to make my textview public because I want to use it in another activity.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    customButtonListener customListner;

    public interface customButtonListener {
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataItem) {
        super(context, R.layout.child_listview, dataItem);
        this.data = dataItem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_listview, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
           // textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
          //  viewHolder.text = textView;
            viewHolder.Button = (ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childButton);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String temp = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.text.setText(temp);
        viewHolder.Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position,temp);
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        ImageButton Button;
    }


     and my mainactivity:
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        customButtonListener {

    private ListView listView;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> dataItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listdata);
        List<String> dataTemp = Arrays.asList(dataArray);
        dataItems.addAll(dataTemp);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataItems);
        adapter.setCustomButtonListner(MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBody = "HHHH";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject            Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
```

Comment: What problem getting with current code?

Comment: what is your problem...

Comment: It makes no sense to make a tepxtview public to use it in another aictivity. You should instead take the text from that textview, put it as extra in an intent with which you start another activity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to share the TextView, but it's content, and according to your code, you are passing it to the listener.

When registering the listener at `getView` you are retrieving the String at `position`, storing it in `temp`, displaying it in the TextView, and passing it to the listener (that's because you declare temp as final, to use it inside the `OnClick`):

```
...
final String temp = getItem(position);
viewHolder.text.setText(temp);
viewHolder.Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (customListner != null) {
            customListner.onButtonClickListner(position,temp);
        }
    }
 });
```

That's the right way to implement it, therefore your problem is not in this part, but...

Later, in the Listener body you receive that String in `value`, but you are not using it:

```
@Override
public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value) {

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "HHHH";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject            Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Just replace `shareBody`by `value`, as it contains the item clicked text. I mean:

Remove `sharebody` and change this line:

```
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, value);
```